# Turning a string in from a text file into a variable identifier

Tags: java, variables

Right, so I've seen a lot of these questions phrased in a similar way but none of these are specifically to what I need. I have a text file like so:

```
~Jerry
10/patio/*
11/bathroom/*
23/home/*
~Jeff
28/patio/*
84/bathroom/*
33/home/*
```

I can read these fine. What I'm trying to accomplish is to take the lines that start with '~' change them into variable names and supply them with all lines below it that don't start with '~'.
Therefore, I'd like to be able to supply the .txt, take the name Jerry and instantiate it as:

```
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath))) {
            for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) 
            {
                if(line.charAt(0) == '~'){
                    line.replace("~","");
                    int[] line = new int[];
                }
                else{
                    //add the line to the Jerry array
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Is there a capability for using stored string to declare new variables? or at least provide the illusion of declaring a new variable so that it can be used with other methods? Or do I need to hard code the declaration in and use a case statement or the like?

Comment: consider Map and HashMap

Comment: The sample shows identical properties which implies you can use a well-defined data model.  If the form of the data is truly dynamic (i.e. you don't know what the properties are) it can be handled with a Map, as suggested by @Abel above.